# Insert unnested array of null values into a double precision column, postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, casting, insert, null

Say I have a double precision column in a postgresql table and try the following INSERTS

Case 1:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (column_name) VALUES (null);
```

Case 2:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (column_name) VALUES (unnest(array[1,null,null,4,5]));
```

Case 3:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (column_name) VALUES (unnest(array[null,null,null,null,null]));
```

Case 1 and 2 execute succesfully, but case 3 returns the following error:

> ERROR:  column "column_name" is of type double precision but
>   expression is of type text LINE 1: INSERT INTO schema.table
>   (column_name) VALUES (unnest(array[nu...
>                                                        ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

**How should I re-write case 3 to re-cast an unnested array of null values into something that can be inserted in a double precision (or any numeric) column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the array of null values to double precision[] or float8[]

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (column_name)
VALUES (unnest(
    array[null,null,null,null,null]::float8[]
));
```

or the cast can be expressed as

```
cast(array[null,null,null,null,null] as double precision[])
```

Comment: @kpurdon: It's good to cast `unnest(arr::float8[])`, and not `unnest(arr)::float8`. [I just found problems with the latter.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452501/null-emements-lost-when-casting-result-of-unnest)