# NULL emements lost when casting result of unnest()

Tags: arrays, postgresql, casting, unnest, set-returning-functions

I stumbled upon very odd behavior with [**`unnest()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html), when casting after expanding an array.

### Introduction

There are three basic syntax variants to use unnest():

1) `SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,4}'::int[]) AS i;`
2) `SELECT i FROM unnest('{2,NULL,4}'::int[]) AS i;`
3) `SELECT i FROM (SELECT unnest('{3,NULL,4}'::int[])) AS t(i);`

All of them include a row with `NULL` in the result as expected

```
 i
---
 1
(null)
 4
```

To cast the array elements to a different type, one can cast the *elements* to a basic type right *after expanding* the array, or cast the *array* itself to a different array type *before expanding*. The first variant seemed slightly simpler and shorter to me:

A) `SELECT unnest('{4,NULL,1}'::int[])::text;`
B) `SELECT unnest('{4,NULL,2}'::int[]::text[]);`

```
 i
---
 4
(null)
 1
```

### Odd behaviour

#### All combinations possible except `2A)`

For some reason one cannot combine `2)` with `A)`

```
SELECT * FROM unnest('{2,NULL,1}'::int[])::text;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"

I can accept that. A rare corner case that has not been implemented for some reason.
All other combinations fly, though:

1A) `SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,1}'::int[])::text AS i;`
<strike>2A) `SELECT i FROM unnest('{2,NULL,1}'::int[])::text AS i;`</strike>
3A) `SELECT i FROM (SELECT unnest('{3,NULL,1}'::int[])::text) AS t(i);`
1B) `SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,2}'::int[]::text[]) AS i;`
2B) `SELECT i FROM unnest('{2,NULL,2}'::int[]::text[]) AS i;`
3B) `SELECT i FROM (SELECT unnest('{3,NULL,2}'::int[]::text[])) AS t(i);`

Same result as above.

#### Really odd behaviour

The following observations concern `A)` exclusively. One can avoid the problem by substituting with `B)`.

As expected, we have seen the `NULL` element in the array resulting in a row with a `NULL` value in all queries so far. However, this is not the case when casting the results from **some** array types to **some** base types.

Here the row with the **NULL value suddenly disappears** (!):

```
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,4}'::int[])::int8;

 i
---
 1
 4
```

#### Examples

I went to see *how deep the rabbit hole goes*. Here are some examples:

`NULL` disappears:

```
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,1}'::int[])::int2;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,2}'::int[])::int8;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,3}'::int[])::real;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,4}'::int[])::float8;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,5}'::int[])::numeric;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,6}'::numeric[])::int2;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,7}'::numeric[])::int8;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,8}'::numeric[])::real;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,9}'::numeric[])::float8;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,a}'::text[])::char;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,b}'::text[])::char(1);
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,c}'::text[])::varchar(10);      -- !!!
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,d}'::varchar[])::varchar(10);   -- !!!
SELECT unnest('{2013-1-1,NULL,2013-1-1}'::date[])::timestamp;
SELECT unnest('{2013-1-1,NULL,2013-1-1}'::timestamp[])::date;
SELECT unnest('{23:11,NULL,23:11}'::time[])::interval;
SELECT unnest('{23:11,NULL,23:11}'::interval[])::time;
```

`NULL` stays:

```
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,1}'::int[])::int4;    -- is really from int to int
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,2}'::int[])::text;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,3}'::int8[])::text;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,4}'::numeric[])::text;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,5}'::text[])::int;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,6}'::text[])::int8;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,7}'::text[])::numeric;
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,8}'::text[])::varchar;    -- !!!
SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,9}'::varchar[])::text;    -- !!!
SELECT unnest('{2013-1-1,NULL,2013-1-1}'::date[])::text;
SELECT unnest('{2013-1-1,NULL,2013-1-1}'::text[])::date;
SELECT unnest('{23:11,NULL,23:11}'::time[])::text;
SELECT unnest('{23:11,NULL,23:11}'::text[])::time;
```

This seems unacceptable.

After testing quite a few combinations, the pattern seems to be:

Cast between related types results in `NULL` elements being lost.
Cast between unrelated types results in `NULL` elements being preserved.
Except that `varchar[]` -> `text` and vice versa trashes this little hypothesis of mine. Or `varchar` and `text` differ more than I thought.

Tested with PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.2. Identical results.
[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/930)

### Questions

Am I missing something here? Can someone explain this behaviour?
If not, the question becomes: Should I go ahead an file a bug report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting SRF function (in FROM clause) is not supported - you cannot use any operator there. Only function call is allowed.

a cast is possible only in column list:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM unnest('{2,NULL,1}'::int[])::text;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM unnest('{2,NULL,1}'::int[])::text;
                                                 ^
postgres=# SELECT v::text FROM unnest('{2,NULL,1}'::int[]) g(v);
   v    
────────
      2
 [null]
      1
(3 rows)
```

Missing row from NULL is probably bug and should be reported

```
postgres=# SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,4}'::int[])::text;
 unnest 
────────
      1
 [null]
      4
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT unnest('{1,NULL,4}'::int[])::numeric;
 unnest 
────────
      1
      4
(2 rows)
```

There is not reason, why NULL rows should be dropped, I think

Comment: Thanks, Pavel. I'll file a bug report for the second part.

Comment: [I reported the bug and Tom Lane immediately found and fixed the problem](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/E1Ub8p6-0006NC-Ja@wrigleys.postgresql.org#E1Ub8p6-0006NC-Ja@wrigleys.postgresql.org). Postgres 9.3 will not exhibit this bug, but they did not back-patch so not to break old code.

Comment: This bug appears to have reemerged in 12.6! I am using unnest to insert XML data into a table using CREATE TABLE tbl AS 
SELECT unnest(xpath('//Record/@symbol', xml_string)::varchar[24][]) as symbol; 
@ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: @Kostas - can you send example?

Comment: @PavelStehule Thanks! While trying to make a reproducible example, I found out that the issue is not with unnest but with xpath. It is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122513/unnest-xpath-doesnt-identify-null-values-correctly