# Unnest (xpath()) doesn't identify NULL values correctly

Tags: xml, postgresql, plpgsql

PostgreSQL version 9.6, using the xml2 extension. I'm attempting to extract rows from XML and insert them into a postgreSQL table. Here's an abbreviated example:

```
ROLLBACK;
BEGIN;
DO $$
DECLARE 
    v_xml xml;
    v_record RECORD;
BEGIN
v_xml := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
    <table>
        <row><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></row>
        <row><a></a><b>5</b><c>6</c></row>
        <row><a>7</a><b>8</b><c>9</c></row> 
    </table>
</root>'::text;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable( col_a text, col_b text, col_c text ) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO temptable VALUES
(
    unnest(xpath('/root/table/row/a/text()', v_xml))::text,
    unnest(xpath('/root/table/row/b/text()', v_xml))::text,
    unnest(xpath('/root/table/row/c/text()', v_xml))::text
);

-- display table contents
FOR v_record IN SELECT * FROM temptable LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'col_a: % col_b: % col_c: %', v_record.col_a, v_record.col_b, v_record.col_c;
END LOOP;
END $$;
```

This works fine when no values are NULL:

```
NOTICE:  col_a: 1 col_b: 2 col_c: 3
NOTICE:  col_a: 4 col_b: 5 col_c: 6
NOTICE:  col_a: 7 col_b: 8 col_c: 9
```

However, for missing or NULL values, unnest() doesn't recognize them properly and uses the next value its column array (that should be read for the **next** row.

To demonstrate, modify the XML as follows (i.e. make the former 4 and 9 values null, or remove the elements completely):

```
<table>
    <row><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></row>
    <row><a></a><b>5</b><c>6</c></row>
    <row><a>7</a><b>8</b><c></c></row>  
</table>
```

Now the following (erroneous) output is produced:

```
NOTICE:  col_a: 1 col_b: 2 col_c: 3
NOTICE:  col_a: 7 col_b: 5 col_c: 6
NOTICE:  col_a: 1 col_b: 8 col_c: 3
NOTICE:  col_a: 7 col_b: 2 col_c: 6
NOTICE:  col_a: 1 col_b: 5 col_c: 3
NOTICE:  col_a: 7 col_b: 8 col_c: 6
```

Some debugging statements revealed the three unnested column arrays to be { 1, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 } and { 3, 6 }. There are no placeholder NULLs to be used as column values while inserting a given row.

Is there another way to implement the unnesting that will properly account for null or missing node values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with `UNNEST`, it's an issue with (or rather, due to) `xpath`, which appears to not include NULL values in the returned array.

`SELECT XPATH('/root/table/row/a/text()', '<root><table><row><a>1</a><a></a><a>3</a></row></table></root>'::XML)` returns `{1,3}`

One way to get around this would be to do an `xpath` on the elements first, and access the values afterwards:

```
SELECT (XPATH('/a/text()', u))[1]
FROM UNNEST(XPATH('/root/table/row/a', '<root><table><row><a>1</a><a></a><a>3</a></row></table></root>'::XML)) u
```

This returns 3 rows (second one is NULL):

```
1

3
```